# How to make BSD printf command ignore locale

Tags: bash, shell, printf

We have a bash script in our project (https://github.com/prsolucoes/gonotin - run.sh) that need use printf for a execution time that is a floating point.

The problem is the printf on osx with locale = pt_br, because it use "," instead of "." and printf command dont know en_us numbers, like "123.45", only "123,45".

My question is about ignore locale on printf or pass a custom locale on printf command.

Can anyone help me?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you check [this](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/104096/locale-dependent-bash-script-how-to-properly-ensure-locale)?

Comment: `LANG=pt_br printf ...`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prepending variable assignments to the command will run it with that variable as a temporary environment variable. So in your case, something like

```
LC_NUMERIC=C printf "> Execution time: %.6f seconds\n\n" $dur
```

should do the trick.

[More info about `LC_*` environment variables](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html#tag_08_02).